# Child DropDownListFor not showing filtered data afer a successful cascade

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc, cascadingdropdown, kendo-dropdown

Greets!

I have an issue involving two Drop-Down Lists. The parent functions in a very simple manner. Upon making a valid selection in the parent DDL, the child DDL enables automatically, and I get to catch an XHR that brings back proper JSON data but then the child DDL fails to render that data.

CSHTML:

```
@* Parent DDL *@
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m=>m.AccountCode)
  .OptionLabel("Service Type...")
  .DataTextField("Name")
  .DataValueField("Code")
  .BindTo(ViewBag.AccountCodes)
  .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 100%", required = "required" })
)

@* Child DDL *@
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.ServiceFinderId)
      .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 100%" })
      .OptionLabel("Select service...")
      .DataTextField("Name").DataValueField("Id")
      .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
      .Height(450)
      .DataSource(source =>
      {
          source.Read(read =>
          {
              read.Action("GetAllServices", "AjaxApi").Type(HttpVerbs.Post)
                  .Data("ServiceFinderIdFilter");
          })
          .ServerFiltering(false);
      })
      .Enable(false)
      .AutoBind(false)
      .CascadeFrom(Html.IdFor(m => m.AccountCode).ToString())
)
```

JavaScript

```
function ServiceFinderIdFilter() {
  return {
    accountCode: $("#" +'@Html.IdFor(m=>m.AccountCode)').val()
  };
}
```

C#

```
public async Task<JsonResult> GetAllServices(string accountCode)
{
    var result = await serviceClient.GetServiceList(true, null, string.Empty, new[] { accountCode });

    if (result == null)
    {
        return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    return Json(result.Select(s => new { Id = s.Code, Name = $"#{s.Code:D4} {s.Name}, Fee: {s.Fee:0.##}" }).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

If I debug, I can see a proper resultset is sent from the controller. In chrome, the XHR call's response is good JSON too. But, in the end, the child DDL show no data

Comment: Could the filter in the child be blocking the rendering of the delivered child information ? What happens if you turn off the filter ?